# Web Service return object generates error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/00a8b7/web-service/). My code can be found here: https://github.com/mudzakkir/testwebservice.git

At `TestConsume.aspx.cs`, this code:

```
var ObjSumClass = new SumClass { First = Num1, Second = Num2 };
var ObjSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var JsonStr = ObjSerializer.Serialize(ObjSumClass);

divSumThroughJson.InnerHtml = ServiceReferenceMyService.GetSumThroughObject1(JsonStr).Sum.ToString();
```

Gives following error:

> Error 1   'FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.GetSumThroughObject1' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context   C:\TohaDoc\Sinau\WebService\FirstWebService\FirstWebService\TestConsume.aspx.cs 32  43  FirstWebService

Open file MyService.asmx.cs, GetSumThroughObject return object. How can we access web service through JSON?

Comment: ASMX pages are legacy technology and should not be used for new development.  If you want to develop web services in .NET take a look at WCF or WebAPI.

Comment: Thank You for the info. Can You give me reference, maybe book? or article where to start to learn WCF and WebAPI? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In that article, he use "ObjMyServiceProxy" object, but I didn't find where this object create.

Then I checked web service Reference 172 line, method name should be "SumOfNums1"

```
public FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.SumClass SumOfNums1(string JsonStr) {
        FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.GetSumThroughObject inValue = new FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.GetSumThroughObject();
        inValue.JsonStr = JsonStr;
        FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.GetSumThroughObject1 retVal = ((FirstWebService.ServiceReferenceMyService.MyServiceSoap)(this)).SumOfNums1(inValue);
        return retVal.GetSumThroughObjectResult;
    }
```

so you need call method like this

```
divSumThroughJson.InnerHtml = ObjMyService.SumOfNums1(JsonStr).Sum.ToString();
```

Comment: ObjMyService maybe name of reference.. and SumOfNums1 method is not available at that namespace.. I am using MS Visual Studio 2010, and .Net 4.. That article is using 3.5 is that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I change the code at this part:

```
divSumThroughJson.InnerHtml =ObjMyServiceProxy.GetSumThroughObject(JsonStr).Sum.ToString();
```

to like this:

```
divSumThroughJson.InnerHtml = new ServiceReferenceMyService.MyServiceSoapClient().SumOfNums1(JsonStr).Sum.ToString();
```

Now it is working..
Is that way is ok?